# Can you find a Darboux basis for any skew integral form on a full-rank lattice in $ℂ^n$ so that the first $n$ vectors are $ℂ$-linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, abelian-varieties, lattices

Any skew bilinear form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ can be brought into the form
\begin{equation}
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0  & \Delta \\
        -\Delta & 0
    \end{pmatrix},
    \quad
    \Delta = \begin{pmatrix}
        \delta_1 &        &     \\
            & \ddots &     \\
            &        & \delta_n
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
by picking a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_{2n}$ of $\mathbb{Z}^n$, where $\delta_i$ are integers satisfying $\delta_i \mid \delta_{i+1}$, see e.g. Griffiths–Harris, *[Principles of algebraic geometry](https://doi.org/10.1002/9781118032527)*, p. 304, or Mumford's book *Abelian varieties*.

**Question:** If the lattice is embedded into $\mathbb{C}^n$, is it always possible to pick the basis such that $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ are a $\mathbb{C}$-basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

**Some thoughts/context:**

- If $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ are not a $\mathbb{C}$-basis then one finds that there is a complex subspace $V \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $\omega\rvert_V = 0$. If $\omega$ is assumed to be positive this leads to a contradiction, but nothing prevents this from happening in the general case.
- Certainly **not any** choice of $\lambda_i$ works, for example if we use coordinates $(x_1 + i y_1, x_2 + iy_2)$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ and pick $\omega = d x_1 \wedge d x_2 + d y_1 ∧ d y_2$, the obvious choice
  \begin{equation}
      \lambda_1 = (1, 0),\quad \lambda_2 = (i, 0),\quad \lambda_3 = (0, 1),\quad \lambda_4 = (0, i)
  \end{equation}
  fails, but this can be fixed by choosing $\lambda_1 = (1, 1)$, which doesn't change the matrix representation of $\omega$.
- I think it might always be possible to "fix" a particular choice of $(\lambda_i)$ by adding an integer multiple of $\lambda_{n+i}$ to $\lambda_i$. This certainly preserves the matrix representation of $\omega$ and might be enough to guarantee we can find a complex basis, see [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633280/can-you-get-a-mathbbc-basis-of-mathbbc2n-from-an-mathbbr-basis).

Comment: Please use TeX rather than Unicode for mathematical symbols; for example, there is a noticeable difference between $δ$ `δ` and $\delta$ `\delta`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks for pointing that out (and the edit). They actually look the same on my computer (when used inside TeX).

Comment: Usually, in this setting, one asks that $\omega$ and complex multiplication are compatible, in the sense that $\omega(\vec{x}, \vec{y}) = \omega(i \vec{x}, i \vec{y})$. Are you imposing this?